# How to force ngFor render

Tags: angular, firebase

I Read array of object from firebase, and I Check if have there any duplicate and count the number of duplicates.
after that, I create a new Object which displays the number of the duplicates and its name.

The data I read from firebase:

```json
a {
  name: "sweet potato",
  color: "orange"
}
b {
  name: "sweet potato",
  color: "orange"
}
c {
  name: "eggplant",
  color: "purple"
}
```

The data after filter:

```json
a {
  name: "potato",
  count: 2
}
b {
  name: "eggplant",
  count: 1
}
```

Typescript code:

```ts
constructor(private firebaseService:FirebaseService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.firebaseService.getData("/name").subscribe(name => {
    this.names=name;
    this.updateMain();
  }) 
}

duplicateFilter() {       // Here we Detect Duplicate
  this.total = [];
  var newArr = [],
      origLen = this.names.length,
      found, x, y;

  for (x = 0; x < origLen; x++) {
    found = undefined;
    for (y = 0; y < newArr.length; y++) {
      if (this.names[x].name === newArr[y]) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      newArr.push(this.names[x].name);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

elementFilter(food) {
  for (var num = 0, i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
    if (this.names[i].name == food) {
      num = num + 1;
    }
  }
  this.total.push(num);
}

objectCreate() {
  this.modal = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.newArr.length; i++) {
    this.modal.push({
      name: this.newArr[i],
      count: this.total[i],
    })
  }
}

updateMain() {
  this.newArr = this.duplicateFilter();

  for (let i in this.newArr) {
    this.elementFilter(this.newArr[i]);
  }
  this.objectCreate();
}
```

HTML code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let modal of modal>
  <div class="center">{{modal.name}}</div>
  <div class="center">{{modal.count}}</div>
</div>
```

the problem is it the info is not updated for any change (adding or editing), even when I send to update the filtered object. its just show the same information.
can i force ngFor render in other way?

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining a new variable. Try `<div *ngFor="let m of modal>`, or more preferrably, `<div *ngFor="let modal of modals>` and update the name of your variable to `modals`.

Comment: still not work, it displays the ngFor in the first time but for any change in the data its not render again or at most it render the same information

Comment: Are you calling `updateMain()` again after you update? Are you updating (posting on) your database?

Comment: yes,I am calling updateMain() after I update the database. in any change on database the function that subcribe will occur and updateMain() is calling.